# Setting up multiple devise registrations controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a devise user model and devise admin model, each one has nested attributes and therefore I need to overwrite each separate model to amend the strong parameters so that my nested attributes will pass through.

How do I go about doing this? I already have overwritten Registrations controller for one of them and its working perfectly, however, If I replicate it and have the controller name as `AdminregistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` (because of course I can't have two called `RegistrationsController`) then it doesn't work.

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you have, lets say user and admin models, you do the following:

controllers/users/registration_controllers.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  def new
      build_resource({})
      #self.resource.regions.build
      #respond_with self.resource
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username << :gender << :email << :password_confirmation << :password << :roles_mask << :phone << :first_name << :last_name << :googleplus
  end 

end
```

controllers/admins/registration_controllers.rb

```
class Admins::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  def new
      build_resource({})
      #self.resource.regions.build
      #respond_with self.resource
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username << :email << :password_confirmation << :password << :roles_mask << :phone << :first_name
  end 

end
```

Obviously you need to change the parameter list, the above are just random examples. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Considering @Georg Keferböck's answer and also improving it for **devise 4**
I would place the **configured_permitted_parameters** method in the applications controller  because the parameters might definitely be required for more than one devise controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    if current_user
      update_attrs = [:password, :password_confirmation,:current_password]
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: update_attrs
    else
      update_attrs = [:password, :password_confirmation, current_password, 
      :phone]
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: update_attrs
    end
  end
end
```

Users registration controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
...
...
end
```

Admins registration controller

```
class Admins::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
...
...
end
```

Ofcourse you would have to use the parameters configured for you own models